Can I install a gMSA from a trusted forest using Install-ADServiceAccount?
I have a need to install a gMSA created in one forest on a server in a trusted forest.  I have created the gMSA, added the AD computer account from the trusted forest to the Domain Local Security group used as the PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword. When I run the Install-ADServiceAccount command on the target server in the trusted domain I am unable to specify a server so it checks for the service account in the local DCs where it will not be found.  I tried using Get-ADServiceAccount which will accept the "-Server" switch and then piping this to the Install-ADServiceAccount but no love there either.  I can use a user-based service account from the originating forest and this I can add as the service principal for the SQL services of interest but then I have to manage the password, etc.  Is there a way to use gMSA accounts cross-forest (2-way trust in place)?
